# Multiplying timedeltas and exponential calculations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta, exponential

I am new to programming and would like to use pandas to calculate exponential decay on some data. However, I am having trouble running multiplication or exponential operations on a time delta values. I think that timedelta values might not be supported for these more complex operations, but surely there is a simple way to do this?

**Input code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('exponential example.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1',
                  usecols = ("A:D"), parse_dates = True)


df['time difference']= df['date 1']-df['date 2']
print(df.head(3))


df['output'] = df['value 1']*np.exp(df['time difference']*.01)
```

**Output:**

```
  sample     date 1     date 2  value 1 time difference

0       1 2018-01-01 2019-01-01        2       -365 days
1       2 2018-01-01 2019-01-01        4       -365 days
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/l225445/Desktop/python test/exponential example.py", line 15, in <module>
    df['output'] = df['value 1']*np.exp(df['time difference']*.01)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 679, in __array_ufunc__
    result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
TypeError: ufunc 'exp' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from what we can see of your data, it seems more natural to define

```py
df['time difference'] = df['date 2'] - df['date 1']
```

so that you get positive values.

Then to be able to do arbitrary calculations with these values, you should pick a unit and convert them to a pure numeric type. E.g. you could do this to get the time differences in days as a numeric column:

```py
df['time difference days'] = df['time difference'].dt.days
```

See the section on Attributes in the pandas Timedelta [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html).

Now your calculation should work, if you just use the numeric Series instead of the Timedelta Series.